# TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION not working but TYPE_ACCELEROMETER is working

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

Hi I wonder if anyone could explain to me why, in this case, `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` doesn't work but `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` works perfectly.

Using `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
    if(se.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
         Log.i("accelerometer test", se.values[1]+"");
    }
}
```

Using `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION`:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
    if(se.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION){
         Log.i("linear test", se.values[1]+"");
    }
}
```

I'm developing on a **Sony Xperia M** which is running **Jellybean 4.1.2 (API 16)**.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare As in, the if statement won't trigger.

Comment: Is `onSensorChanged()` being called at all? Does that device have a `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` sensor?

Comment: Not for `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION`. It was added in API 9 so I would assume so.

Comment: Are you using `getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION)` for your `registerListener()` call? If so, is `getDefaultSensor()` returning a `Sensor`?